# what does this extra private[class]() in scala class definition mean?

Tags: scala

I'm reading over someone elses code on Scala in order to learn the language a little better, but I'm stumped at what the following means "privateutil" If I just saw the [util] I would suspect that it was some sort of specific generic? but its got it's own private modifier?

```
class RPGPluginProperties private[util]() extends Properties {
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#private:

> A private modifier can be qualified with an identifier C (e.g.
>   private[C]) that must denote a class or package enclosing the
>   definition. Members labeled with such a modifier are accessible
>   respectively only from code inside the package C or only from code
>   inside the class C and its companion module.

So in this case the private modifier is making the no-args constructor private to the util class/package.

To declare the class private to the scope util, it would be private[util] class RPGPluginProperties...

Comment: So is the class private, or is the constructor private?

Comment: The constructor. To declare the class private to the scope util, it would be `private[util] class RPGPluginProperties...`